Api call to load blog posts saying blocked by orb
I have a blog application in which the home page shows the blog posts of all authors with the images of the blog post and their profile pic...but the images are not being displayed and when I check the network requests it says(failed)net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB but also I don't have to say when users create a new blogpost the images appear for a period of time and when we revisit the website later the image is gone
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/posts`);

            console.log("API Response:", response); // Log the API response

            setPosts(response?.data);

        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error fetching posts:", err); // Log any errors
        }

        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchPosts();

}, []);

I tried console logging the res but see no problem there the user info is being displayed

If images are coming from a different domain/subdomain, check your CORS headers.

net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB indicates that the browser is blocking the request due to security settings. That's because you're trying to load resources  from a different domain than the one your website is hosted on.

well my backend and frontend is deployed on render seperately so what changes do i have to make in the server configuration? also https://mern-blog-application-backend-1.onrender.com/uploads/kendrick-lamar-pimp-butterfly-cover-1200x6303ca86141-34a7-4532-9fcb-e8932a363d42.jpg is where the images are coming from do i have to allow the server to load the resources from here?
